# shell's logic AND, cmd1 && cmd2, it's reversed, right?

Tags: shell, logic, return-value, radix

We know `&&` means logical `AND`, so:

```
true && true  => true
false && true => false
```

When we work in *Shell* (Bash here), successful command call returns `0`.  Does the shell change `0` to `non-zero` before `AND` operation?  Or *Shell* just reverse the normal `logics`?

As an example:

```
cat file1 && cat file2
```

`file2` will be `cat-ed` only if `file1` can be `cat-ed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash, logical `true` is represented as `0` while logical `false` is represented as a non-zero value. This allows the exit value of a command to be used in a logical operation.

You can find out more by browsing the [documentation on bash operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html).

One [common idiom](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/list-cons.html#LISTCONSREF) is to chain commands using `&&` so that if any command in the chain fails, the following commands are not executed:

```
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3
```

Comment: It can happen this way: `if [ -f file1 ] && [ -f file2 ]; then cat file1 && cat file2 ;fi`

Answer (score 5):

In the shell (bash included) `&&` does mean logical AND.  The parameters of `&&` can be commands that will be evaluated according to their return value -- a return value of 0 indicates success (true), other values failure (false).

So in a C/C++ sense it is reversed (in C/C++ and its ilk 0 = false, other = true), but from the shell's perspective it is not (success = true, fail = false)

UPDATE: changed explanation based on comment that `&&` does not necesarily involve execution of commands

Comment: Not exactly, `&&` is a genuine logical operator in bash. execution is a side effect. This is similar to C: `if( (method() && method2()) == 0);` will never execute `method2()` if `method` returns false.